# Parsing a table on a webpage without id's or classes - using Nokogiri or xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I wish to parse through a epinions.com page to gather some statistics about a few companies. Epinions have almost no id's or classes, so it's quite difficult to parse the site.

I need to loop through all `<tr bgcolor="white">` objects. I have put in 2 samples of this.

**From the sample 1, I need to extract:**

The `alt` on this line:

```
<img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/ratings/checks_sm_5.0.gif" alt="Store Rating: 5.0" width="79" height="13" border="0">
```

The `href` this line:

```
<a href="/content_218093751940" style="text-decoration:none;">CHUMBO ROCKS!</a>
```

The `author` at this line:

```
<span class="rgr">by <a  href="/user-whitey436" itemprop="author">whitey436</a>,&nbsp;Jan 18, 2006
```

*Here is sample 1:*

```
<tr bgcolor="white">
  <td style="padding:10px 5px" align="right" valign="top" height="100%">
    <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" width=100% height="100%">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td class="rkr" nowrap>Overall Rating:</td>
        <td width=80>
          <img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/ratings/checks_sm_5.0.gif" alt="Store Rating: 5.0" width="79" height="13" border="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <span class="rgr">
        <tr>
          <td class="rgr" nowrap>Ease of Ordering:</td>
          <td>
            <img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/e3/quant_5.gif" width=80 height=11>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="rgr" nowrap>Customer Service:</td>
          <td>
            <img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/e3/quant_5.gif" width=80 height=11>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="rgr" nowrap>Selection:</td>
          <td>
            <img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/e3/quant_5.gif" width=80 height=11>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="rgr" nowrap>On-Time Delivery:</td>
          <td>
            <img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/e3/quant_5.gif" width=80 height=11>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </span>
      <tr valign="bottom" height="100%">
        <td class="rkb" colspan="2">
          <div align="center"> </div>
          <div align="center"> </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td style="padding:10px;" colspan=2 width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
    <h2 style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:87%; color:#000000; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:0px;">
      <a href="/content_218093751940" style="text-decoration:none;">CHUMBO ROCKS!</a>
    </h2>
    <span style="line-height:110%">
      <span class="rgr">by <a  href="/user-whitey436" itemprop="author">whitey436</a>,&nbsp;Jan 18, 2006
      Rated a <span style="color:#000;">Very Helpful Review</span> by the Epinions community</span>
    </span>
    <span class="rkr">
      <div style="padding:5px 0px"> Its just this simple, I tried buying this receiver from another online supplier who had the lowest price only to find they didnt have any of these units and they wanted to sell me extra warranty then tried to sell a different model in stock from Yamaha  ...</div>
      <b>
        <a  href="/content_218093751940">Read the full review</a>
      </b>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**From the sample 2, I need to extract:**

The `alt` on this line:

```
<img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/ratings/checks_sm_5.0.gif" alt="Store Rating: 5.0" width="79" height="13" border="0">
```

The `href` on this line:

```
<a  href="/content_224519491204">Read more</a>
```

The `author` at this line:

```
<span class="rgr">by <a  href="/user-whitey436" itemprop="author">whitey436</a>,&nbsp;Jan 18, 2006
Rated a <span style="color:#000;">Very Helpful Review</span> by the Epinions community</span>
```

*Here is sample 2:*

```
<tr bgcolor="white">
  <td style="padding:10px 5px" align="right" valign="top">
    <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" border="0" width=100%>
      <tr>
        <td class="rkr" nowrap>Overall Rating:</td>
        <td width=80>
          <img src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/ratings/checks_sm_5.0.gif" alt="Store Rating: 5.0" width="79" height="13" border="0">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='rgr' >&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <img src='http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/spacer.gif' width=80 height=11>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td style="padding:10px;" colspan=2 width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
    <span class="rgr">Mar 27, 2006 <br>(Not Yet Rated)</span><br>
    <span class="rkr"> Very helpful in giving me the information I needed to make a purchase.<br><b>
      <a  href="/content_224519491204">Read more</a>
    </b></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some Nokogiri code to print out the information you want using XPath:

```
xml.xpath("//tr[@bgcolor='white']").each do |el|
  # Get the "Overall rating" tr block from the first td and get (first) img alt
  puts el.at_xpath("td[1]//tr[td/text()='Overall Rating:']//img/@alt")
  # Get the first link from the second td that contains "content" and get href
  puts el.at_xpath("td[2]//a[contains(@href, '/content')][1]/@href")
  # Get the (first) link that has an itemprop author value and get the href
  puts el.at_xpath("td[2]//a[@itemprop='author']/@href")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use Nokogiri will be ok.

to get alt, get back all the image tags and keep the img tag with the specified src

```
imgs = doc.css('img[src="http://img.epinions.com/images/epi_images/ratings/checks_sm_5.0.gif"]')
```

to get back the href

```
links = doc.css('a[href*="/content"]')
```

to get back the author

```
links = doc.css('a[href*="/user"]')
```

Comment: You can put attributes in your css you know: `doc.css('a[href*="/content"]')`

Comment: Yes, but don't add spaces. They don't belong there.